# SQL query taking more time when columns reduced

Tags: sql, sql-server, execution-time

I have a select query with 100+ columns from 15 tables and more then 100000 rows. And the execution time of this query is around 15 mnts.
Now when I have reduced number of columns to 50 and comments out respective tables. 
As per my understanding new query should take less than 15 mnts but now the execution time increased to 4 hrs :(.

Please suggest.

Comment: Less columns shouldn't matter (much), but how the query is structured and corresponding indexes.  Can you post the query with a few columns, and all your JOIN criteria / WHERE conditions to the query.  That would give best option to getting a solution for you.

Comment: Please add more information to your question, if you want an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without more detailed information, I suggest rebuilding the indexes on all tables involved in the query (and update any remaining column statistics):

```
DBCC DBREINDEX('MyTable')
go

UPDATE STATISTICS MyTable WITH FULLSCAN, COLUMNS
go
```

[The usual warning/caveats about running on a production server apply].

Comment: But still the old query is taking less time.

Comment: without more detailed information, I suggest you rebuild and then report back....

Comment: please post the actual queries and full table schema (inc. indexes)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you a few optimizations:

1. Make sure that your tables have indexes; the columns used in WHERE conditions or in JOIN conditions needs to be in those indexes
2. Make sure you don't use '*' selector, unless is needed;